# WPF Listbox with checkboxes appearing blank, added dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, checkbox

I'm trying to populate a listbox with a series checkbox entries, however once running the code below the listbox has blank entries in it, which are selectable, i.e. a blue bar appears.  However neither the text or checkbox appears.

```
for (int num = 1; num <= 10; num++)
{
   CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
   checkBox.Text = "sheet" + num.ToString();
   checkBox.Name = "checkbox" + num.ToString();

   thelistbox.Items.Add(checkBox);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to create a list of data -- in your case, a list of numbers (or a list of strings (sheet1, sheet2, etc).  You can then assign that list of numbers to thelistbox.ItemsSource.  Inside the XAML of your listbox, set the ItemTemplate to include a CheckBox and bind the number to the text of the checkbox.

Comment: Good idea, I catch your drift.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
checkBox.Text = "sheet" + num.ToString();
```

to

```
checkBox.Content = "sheet" + num.ToString();
```

With that change, I was able to use your example successfully.

Comment: Strange there's doesn't seem to be a definition for .Content

Comment: Ah, I think that might help explain it!  The winforms checkbox has a text property (but no content), whereas the WPF checkbox has a content property (but no text).  It would appear that you are using a winforms checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Brian's comment, here is an outline of a simple checkbox list in C# wpf.   This will need more code to handle checking/unchecking boxes and general post-interaction handlers.  This setup presents the difference in elements on two lists of objects (defined elsewhere) in a checkbox list.

The XAML

```xml
...
    <ListBox Name="MissingNamesList" ItemsSource="{Binding TheMissingChildren}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
...
```

The supporting C# code:

```
...
public partial class MissingNamesWindow : Window
{    
    // Make this accessible from just about anywhere
    public ObservableCollection<ChildName> TheMissingChildren { get; set; }

    public MissingNamesWindow()
    {
        // Build our collection so we can bind to it later
        FindMissingChildren();

        InitializeComponent();

        // Set our datacontext for this window to stuff that lives here
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void FindMissingChildren()
    {
        // Initialize our observable collection
        TheMissingChildren = new ObservableCollection<ChildName>();

        // Build our list of objects on list A but not B
        List<ChildName> names = new List<ChildName>(MainWindow.ChildNamesFromDB.Except(
                                                    MainWindow.ChildNamesFromDisk).ToList());

        // Build observable collection from out unique list of objects
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            TheMissingChildren.Add(name);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Hope that clarifies a bit.